# Linq DataTable reuse concatenated variable

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I am doing in my LINQ on a datatable.

```
var result = resTable.Rows.Where(r => Map.ContainsKey(string.Concat(r[HeaderCol].ToString().Trim(),dot,r[FooterCol].ToString().Trim(),dot,r[TypeCol].ToString().Trim())))
                                              .GroupBy(r => string.Concat(r[HeaderCol].ToString().Trim(), dot, r[FooterCol].ToString().Trim(), dot, r[TypeCol].ToString().Trim()))
                                              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                            g => g.GroupBy(r => DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[DateCol]))
                                                                  .ToDictionary(c => c.Key,
                                                                                c => c.Select(r => new ResultObj(DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[ResultDateCol]), new Decimal((double)r[PriceCol])))
                                                                                      .ToList()));
```

I am creating a key from column values and need to use it in group by as well.

```
string.Concat(r[HeaderCol].ToString().Trim(), dot, r[FooterCol].ToString().Trim(), dot, r[TypeCol].ToString().Trim())
```

Any way I can do string concat only once and use it twice in LINQ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is necessary, but here t you want.

```
var result = resTable.Rows.Select(r => new {r, res = string.Concat(r[HeaderCol].ToString().Trim(),dot,r[FooterCol].ToString().Trim(),dot,r[TypeCol].ToString().Trim())})
     .Where(r => Map.ContainsKey(r.res))
     .GroupBy(r => r.res)
          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
              g => g.GroupBy(r => DateTime.FromOADate((double)r.r[DateCol]))
                    .ToDictionary(c => c.Key,
                            c => c.Select(r => new ResultObj(DateTime.FromOADate((double)r.r[ResultDateCol]), new Decimal((double)r.r[PriceCol])))
                                .ToList()));
```